# WPF styles: difference between x:Name and x:Type

Tags: wpf, styles

While defining style in resource dictionary you can use either

```
x:Name="xyz"
```

and

```
x:Type="xyz".
```

and can reference this style in XAML like {StaticResource xyz}.

Most examples use 'x:Key', and the difference between 'name' and 'key' is that using 'x:name' lets you use this style definition code-behind?

**FIXES:**
The question is totally wrong. What was intended to be asked was the difference between x:Key and x:Name. But didn't go trying this code myself, but was just relying on memories - thought I have both in ResourceDictionary, which was wrong. And I also didn't have such code in

```
 <xxx.Resources >
```

sections, since it doesn't work either. You can't reference Style that doesn't have x:Key (x:Name doesn't work here), and adding two styles without x:Key throws exception since both get the same (empty?) key in dictionary.

Ray puts all the difference in a very nice way, thanks.
My fault

Comment: This is a trick question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**This is a trick question.**  In fact, you **cannot** define a style in a ResourceDictionary using either

```
x:Type="xyz"
```

or

```
x:Name="xyz"
```

Here is the difference:

- `x:Type="xyz"` is not valid XAML syntax.
- `x:Name="xyz"` is actually valid XAML syntax that names an object (which affects the generation of code-behind) but does not provide a dictionary key.
- `x:Key="xyz"` is also valid XAML syntax that provides a dictionary key but does not name an object.

In a dictionary a key is required, so you must specify `x:Key` (except that for FrameworkTemplate and its subclasses the key can be inferred from the TargetType or DataType).  In a dictionary you may also specify `x:Name` if desired but it does not affect the key.

Note that `x:Type` is a markup extension that is predefined by XAML, whereas `x:Name` and `x:Key` are actual XAML keywords.  So `x:Type` can only be used in markup extension syntax as the value of a property:

```
something="{x:Type whatever}"
```

whereas `x:Name` and `x:Key` are attributes that can be used on elements.

Comment: It's a double trick question because actually **neither of them works**.  You can't define a style in a ResourceDictionary using `x:Name="xyz"` either.  Only x:Key works.

Comment: No kidding! How did I miss that? And now what am I going to do? Delete my answer? Amend it? I guess I'll amend it. Thanks itowlson.

Comment: Thanks for response.  
Please, let me know if I should delete this question, or edit its text to make it not tricky.

Answer (score 2):

x:Name allows you to create a reference that you can use by name.

x:type allows you to create a reference that is used by that type

for instance

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    ...
</Style>
```

creates a style that will automatically affect buttons